# Google Sign-In for server-side apps: exchange of a valid authorization code to a token - Bad Request Error (Error: redirect_uri_mismatch)

Tags: google-api, google-openid, google-identity, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google Sign-In (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow) for my application. I've managed to successfully get an authorisation code, but when I try to exchange it to a token, I get the following response.

**Error Response:**

```
{
    "error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
    "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

I have already tried adding a number of redirect URLs to the google console but this issue still persists. Please refer to redirect URLs below.

```
http://localhost:49188/oauthcallback.aspx
https://localhost:49188/oauthcallback.aspx
https://localhost:49188/oauthcallback.aspx
http://localhost/oauthcallback.aspx
https://localhost/oauthcallback.aspx
http://localhost/oauthcallback.aspx
https://localhost/oauthcallback.aspx
```

I've tried multiple requests using different token endpoints, but it doesn't resolve this issue.

**1st endpoint:**

```
POST URI: www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code={code}&
client_id={xxx}.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret={client_secret}&
redirect_uri=https://localhost:49188/oauthcallback.aspx&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

**2nd endpoint:**

```
POST URI: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code={code}&
client_id={xxx}.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret={client_secret}&
redirect_uri=https://localhost:49188/oauthcallback.aspx&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

I expect to get the proper token response but refer to below JSON as it is the response that I get.

**Expected Response:**

```
{
  "access_token":"1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
  "expires_in":3920,
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "refresh_token":"1/xEoDL4iW3cxlI7yDbSRFYNG01kVKM2C-259HOF2aQbI"
}
```

**Error Response**

```
{
    "error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
    "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

Comment: What is the authorization URL you send users to in order to obtain this authorization code? The full request for user authorization should contain a redirect_uri that needs to match the one you're presenting on the token exchange call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user2705223 You have highlighted a good point. So, if you use ux_mode="popup" or default, It seems the JS SDK adds the domain host as the default redirect URL instead of the URL specified when initialising, which is pretty weird.

Comment: I can confirm this is true. Using `ux_mode="popup"` will just implicitly set the redirect url from client side to be your domain host, and no other special URL. You'll have to add that to your "Authorized redirect URIs" in the Google cloud console for your project id.